# Faster way to convert ctypes array to python list?

Tags: python, ctypes

I was wondering if someone could advise me whether there is a better/faster approach to read data from my C program that outputs two lists of size *n*. I am using `ctypes` to call the C program.

The loop I show below works by iterating over a number of scans. For each scan two lists are produced (`msX, msY`). The `c_float` data is extracted by using list comprehension loop. Is there a better/faster way to convert the `c_float_Array`  obtained from mzP and mzI to `msX` and `msY`?

```
for scan in xrange(nScans):
    mzP = (c_float * nPoints)() # pointer to list 1, c_float_Array
    mzI = (c_float * nPoints)() # pointer to list 2,  c_float_Array
    mlLib.readData(filePointer, 1, scan, byref(mzP), byref(mzI))
    # The slow part...
    msX = [mzP[i] for i in xrange(nPoints)] # list with mzP data
    msY = [mzI[i] for i in xrange(nPoints)] # list with mzI data
```

Let me know if my question is not clear.
Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Try with PyPy https://www.pypy.org with CPython there is nothing faster that list comprehension.

Comment: `msX = mzP[:]` would be faster than a list comprehension, but why do you need a list instead of directly using the ctypes array? If a ctypes array is missing some method that you need, maybe an `array.array` will suffice? Starting with `msX = array.array('f', [0]) * nPoints`, you can get a ctypes array that shares it via `mzP = (c_float * nPoints).from_buffer(msX)`.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I tried your first suggestion and this reduces the runtime to approx. 45% which is great. I will have a look at your other suggestion to see whether it will be suitable. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you prefer, you can convert to an array with `np.ndarray`:

```
msX = np.ndarray((nPoints, ), 'f', mzP, order='C')    
msY = np.ndarray((nPoints, ), 'f', mzI, order='C')
```

Comment: It does increase the speed by about 20 % on top of what @eryksun suggested. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The answer is to use NumPy.  You can use NumPy to allocate an array, pass a pointer to its data to your C API which will populate it, and then at the end if you are desperate for a `list` you can call `tolist()` on the NumPy array.  However,  you will likely find that keeping the data stored in a NumPy array instead of a list allows you to accelerate downstream processing.

Comment: what if the array to give in input is not empty?

Answer (score 2):

I may be missing something, but this works for me:

```
from ctypes import c_float

arr = (c_float * 3)(1,2,3)
arr[:]
#Result: [1.0, 2.0, 3.0]
```